# What are some good frameworks for creating desktop multitouch-webapplications - not mobile apps?

Tags: frameworks, multi-touch

Looking for some frameworks or libraries to create a webapp that can be controlled by custom multitouch (MT) gestures - when run on a MT-hardware like a MT-laptop,  MT-operating system (e.g. win7) and in a MT-browser (e.g. Firefox 4). I'm not interested in creating a mobile app.

That means my implementation of the website should use something like html 5, css and javascript.

I saw script.aculo.us - are there any alternatives?

Thanks